# What do I need to do to play music using createMediaElementSourceNode?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-audio-api

I'm trying to connect a `MediaElementAudioSourceNode` and a `gainNode` to change the volume of an mp3 file.
[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-bush-7zip7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)
The code was created with reference to the following pages.
[AudioContext.createMediaElementSource() - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaElementSource)

But the music will not play.
What is missing in my code?

Below is the source code.

---

```js
let audio, gainNode;

const App = () => {
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    audio = new Audio("/piano.mp3");
    const sourceNode = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
    gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
    sourceNode.connect(gainNode);
    gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    return () => audioCtx.close();
  }, []);

  const playPause = () => {
    if (playing) {
      audio.pause();
      setPlaying(false);
      return;
    }
    audio.play();
    setPlaying(true);
  };

  const cahngeVolume = (e) => (gainNode.gain.value = e.target.value);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={playPause} style={{ display: "block" }}>
        {playing ? "Pause" : "Play"}
      </button>
      <div>
        <span>Volume</span>
        <input type="range" onChange={cahngeVolume} step="any" />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

---

Remove the following code in useEffect and you can play the audio.

```js
const sourceNode = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
sourceNode.connect(gainNode);
```

Comment: Not at all into react-js, when is called the function returned by `useEffect`? Also, do you have anything popping in your JS console?

Comment: The function returned by ```useEffect``` will be called when the component is unmounted.

Comment: Running the codesandbox in Firefox you have an warning message in the console stating *The HTMLMediaElement passed to createMediaElementSource has a cross-origin resource, the node will output silence.*. You need to provide this media in accordance with the same-origin policies. Simply setting the `crossOrigin` attribute of this audio element works in codesandbox. (`audio = new Audio(); audio.crossOrigin = "anonymous"; audio.src = "/piano.mp3";`) But maybe you'll have to set up your server so it sends the proper Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers though.

Comment: Sound could be played. Thanks a lot!There is a problem that the music is distorted when manipulating the gainNode, but the music played back, so it's solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
audio.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
```

Thanks to Kaiido.